# increasing 'extent' of small raster to be same size as large raster in R

Tags: raster, r, extents, extract-by-mask, dimensions

I have a satellite image with dimensions (11418, 13790, 1). The resolution is 10m. I have two other rasters, which fall inside of my satellite image which are the same resolution and crs.

How would I go about enhancing the `extent` of small rasters to the size of my satellite image, and then create NA values?

To be clear, I'm looking for a workflow which I think involves changing the extent of my small rasters to the large one using the `extent` argument and then using the `mask` function?

Comment: Note if you want to comment on an answer do it as a "Add a comment" instead of creating a new answer! The site should evolve to have one Question per Question, then a bunch of Answers (that answer the Question), then one Answer will get "Accepted" as correct, or the best!

Answer (score 3):

Let's make an example with some sample rasters that represent your situation, hopefully. First a big raster with extent from (0,0) to (100,100):

```
big = raster(matrix(1:100,10,10))
extent(big)=c(0,100,0,100)
```

Now a small raster spanning part of that from (10,20) to (20,30):

```
small = raster(matrix(1:100,10,10))
extent(small)=c(10,20,20,30)
```

Now use `extend` to expand the bounds of `small` to the extent of `big`

```
smallextend = extend(small, big)
```

which is this:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 100, 100, 10000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 100, 0, 100  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 100  (min, max)
```

Plotting shows `smallextend` stretching out to the extent of `big`, but padded with `NA` values:

[image]

Note the extent might not be exact if the resolution doesn't exactly fit into the big raster, for example:

```
> extent(small2) = c(11.23, 23.7, 22.1, 33.4)
> plot(small2, add=TRUE)
> extend(small2, big)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 89, 80, 7120  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1.247, 1.13  (x, y)
extent     : 0.007, 99.767, -0.5, 100.07  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 100  (min, max)
```

you can see the output extent isn't quite the same as `big` because the `small2` is not made of 1x1 cells.